# i am new to ubuntu so just a bit of queries before i install it over my windows

Tags: networking, internet

How would I setup internet connection in saucy salamander and how can I get apps using the sudo apt comands and yeah tell me some basic commands for like troubleshooting problems related to memory and HDD etc. waiting for your reply

I use a internet service provider who has just used the command ncpa.cpl to go to the device in windows and configured its ipv4 properties to let me use internet via their website 180.188.246.5

So could u just tell me to configure and setup internet on Ubuntu.

Comment: Official Ubuntu Guidance is from [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com). You can Google with your problem summery with askubuntu.com (at the the end) to get askubuntu answer. Also take a look at [here](http://allfreeubuntu.blogspot.com). I have posted some guidence for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Normally internet should work out of the box. If for some reason this does not work with your provider we need to know why and what we have to address manually.
A lot can be changed with ncpa and only stating that you have access via their website is not very clear, do you mean they run a proxy at that address, or is this the address from their gateway? Do you get an ip-adres automatically or do we have to assign by hand? etc
To install a program through commandline you use: sudo apt-get install programname
,but if you are a newbie I would start with the graphical interface.
Keep your questions simple, you now ask for several things in one item, and just some troubleshooting commands can take books to describe if you do not properly address what you want to find/fix.